# Dell Vostro 1520 BIOS update failed - machine is out of warranty and Dell will not assist

Tags: laptop, bios

During BIOS upgrade of my Vostro 1520 laptop (Windows 7 Ultimate, 64bit) their update software failed to complete. In fact the software hung.

Now the computer will not turn on, the BIOS does not come up much less POST.

Dell will not talk to me on the phone as the computer is not under warranty.

I'm very frustrated since in my mind they planted a Trojan ruining my computer - it's not my fault their software failed, many others seem to have this problem.

I'm hoping someone has instructions on flashing the BIOS,  I'm handy with computers but dont know if there is a recovery mode for the BIOS, does it recover over USB/CD/HD, where to get the BIOS file.

Any help will be appreciated.

I'm so disappointed with Dell. They used to be better than this.

Answer (score 1):

Try these

Unplug the AC power remove the main battery, hold the power button down for 20 seconds, plug in AC only and see if it recovers.

Another method is to follow the above instructions, except this time remove the cmos battery also, on some models this requires complete dis-assembly of the laptop, leave the cmos battery out overnight, put it back in next day, connect AC only and if the bios posts (Dell splash screen), use F2 to immediately enter bios set up and set the date and time, do this before Windows loads.

*Note the polarity of the cmos battery when you remove it, re insert it the same way it came out.

If this fails you will need to send it out for a bios repair

http://www.fixedbios.com/

Update:

Looks like that model does require complete dis-assembly to reach the cmos battery

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/vos1520/en/SM/td_coin.htm

.

Comment: This is a little outdated, but I had this EXACT same problem with the same laptop, and the first solution (remove battery, hold down power, etc) worked for me! Thanks a lot